# Vertically centered tables

Tags: tables

I know this question has been answered many times but I can't get this to work. I'm a beginner, I started learning Latex last week.

I have two types of tables. I got them to be full width and horizontally centered, but I just can't get the vertical alignment to work.

My tables look like this: 
[image: My tables look like this:]

What I want is:

- full page width
- equal column width
- horizontally centered
- vertically centered
- every other row colored
- rows slightly higher than default

Now how can I get my table cells vertically centered? Alternative solutions are welcome.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

%Tabelle breite gleich & zentriert
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} 

\begin{document}  

\begin{table}[h]
\rowcolors  {2}{lightgray}{white}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{l|C|C}
\rowcolor{white}
Aufgabe & Fall 1 & Fall 2     \\[1ex] \cline{1-3}
Anlage von $K_0$ & \multicolumn{2}{c}{5943,79}  \\ [1ex]
Erwirtschafteter Ertrag & 5999,40 & 10.462,50 \\ [1ex]
Anlage von Erträgen & 7.288,48 & 12.710,56 \\ [1ex]
\end{tabularx}%
}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\rowcolors  {2}{lightgray}{white}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{C|C|C}
\rowcolor{white}
x / y & z / a & b / c   \\[1ex] \cline{1-3}
100 & 200 & 300  \\ [1ex]
312 & 469 & 623 \\ [1ex]
432 & 862 & 527 \\ [1ex]
\end{tabularx}%
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please provide complete small document (copy in your editor and past here) which start with `\documentclass{...}` and `end{document}`, which demonstrate your problem. Your link can be dead after while and people here will not be able to know, what was your problem.

Comment: The first step is to learn how to paste the code *here*. I at least won't follow your link for such a question.

Comment: Really sorry! I figured it out now and changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

%Tabelle breite gleich & zentriert
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}     % <---
\rowcolors  {2}{lightgray}{white}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{L|C|C} % <---
\rowcolor{white}
Aufgabe                 & Fall 1     & Fall 2           \\
    \hline
Anlage von $K_0$        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{5943,79}   \\
Erwirtschafteter Ertrag & 5999,40   & 10.462,50         \\
Anlage von Erträgen     & 7.288,48  & 12.710,56         \\
\end{tabularx}%
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}     % <---
\rowcolors  {2}{lightgray}{white}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{C|C|C} % <---
\rowcolor{white}
x / y & z / a & b / c   \\
    \cline{1-3}
100 & 200 & 300         \\
312 & 469 & 623         \\
432 & 862 & 527         \\
\end{tabularx}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Addendum:** An alternativer solution is use the `cellspace` packet and larger spaces above and below of cells' contents:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{cellspace, 
            tabularx}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{2ex}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{2ex}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

%Tabelle breite gleich & zentriert
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\rowcolors  {2}{lightgray}{white}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{SL | SC| SC} % <---
\rowcolor{white}
Aufgabe                 & Fall 1     & Fall 2           \\
    \hline
Anlage von $K_0$        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{5943,79}   \\
Erwirtschafteter Ertrag & 5999,40   & 10.462,50         \\
Anlage von Erträgen     & 7.288,48  & 12.710,56         \\
\end{tabularx}%
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\rowcolors  {2}{lightgray}{white}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{SC| SC| SC} % <---
\rowcolor{white}
x / y & z / a & b / c   \\
    \cline{1-3}
100 & 200 & 300         \\
312 & 469 & 623         \\
432 & 862 & 527         \\
\end{tabularx}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorcery! This seems to be a workaround since you can't use it with really big row heights (e.g. \renewcommand\arraystretch{5}) but for my purposes, this works. Thank you!

Comment: I select `\extrarowheight` according to your use of `\\ [1ex]`. if you have some other demand, you should note this in question. :-). After your comment, your question is not clear anymore. If you for example have cells with multi line context, than proposed solution is the best.

Comment: Yes, the rows should be bigger, not default height. That's why I used [1ex]. But your solution works!

Comment: @latexcanbedifficult, see addendum to my answer. If answer solve your problem, you can accept it (by clicking on the check mark at the top left side of answer) :-)

Comment: That's an even better solution, wow! Thank you, it looks great! I have another question, if you don't mind. Is there a way to vertically align ONLY the table head but nothing else? I have some tables that use the default height but the table head is a bit bigger, so I would like to center those.

Comment: @latexcanbedifficult, hm, in above MWE no one rows have specual vertical centered contents. It appears so, since all cells have only one line of text. So, this impression will left in column headers, but disappear in other rows with multi line cells. Do I understood you correctly? If not, please ask new question with MWE, which demonstrate your problem.

Comment: I have updated the question above! I only want the table head to be bigger, the rest should be default height.

Comment: @latexcanbedifficult, I ask you for new question, not editing this one. This is already solved (in original version). With your editing of this, you make my answer obsolete.